# Class cannot return object

Tags: php, function, class

i am trying to create some class and method on PHP, and some function is good output, but in last output i cannot throw a variable, this is my class.

here i call the class,

```
$fields = array('nik');
    $query = new Query();
    $query
        ->select($fields)
        ->from('data_asset_hw')
        ->orderby('nik','DESC')
        ->execute('fetchAll');

    print json_encode($query);
```

select, from and orderby is good. But i cant get the output from the last function (execute), just null object i found `{}`.

See my class below, on method `execute()`.
if i manually print the query object, and the output is normally. But if i using return this `$query`. I found output is `null`. Maybe i miss something?

```
<?php
Class Query 
{
private $query; 
function __construct(){
    $this->query = "";
}

function select($fields=array()){
    if(!is_array($fields)){
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT %s ",$fields);
        $this->query .= $sql;
        return $this;
    }else{
        $fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT `%s` ", $fields);
        $this->query .= $sql;
        return $this;
    }
}

function from($table){
    $table = trim(strtolower(stripslashes($table)));
    $sql = sprintf("FROM %s ", $table);
    $this->query .= $sql;
    return $this;
}

function orderby($field,$order){
    $sql = sprintf("ORDER BY %s %s", $field,$order);
    $this->query .= $sql; 
    return $this;
}

function where($command){
    $sql = sprintf("WHERE %s ", $command);
    $this->query .= $sql;
    return $this;
}

function execute($fetch){
    try{
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        (string)$this->query;
        $query = $database->prepare($this->query);

        if(!$query){
            throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
        }

        $execute = $query->execute();
        if(!$execute){
            throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
        }
        // output is normally
        print_r($query->$fetch());
        // cannot return object
        return $query->$fetch();
    } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($pdoException, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
}
```

i found my error just add public $output; and return $this->output = $query->$fetch(). and wata..... i already done.
Thanks
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Result is already fetched with `print_r`. You __can't__ fetch it twice, so remove `print_r` line.

Comment: How about `$result = $query->...->execute('fetchAll'); echo json_encode($result)`? Also, all those `print_r` statements are going to ruin your JSON response

Comment: is that `$` in front of `fetch` intentional? in `$query->$fetch()` edit: ah, i see it now ... however, u_mulder is correct then.

Comment: @Jakumi i use $ for call the function fetch or fetchAll.

Comment: @Phil i got error if use execute('fetchAll')

Comment: @Jakumi I think it is. Seems it is OP's intention to pass the `PDOStatement` method name as an argument

Comment: @ikwijaya oh no. It's a shame errors don't come with any messages or status codes. I guess you're totally stuck now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add public $output;

and use that with 
$this->output = $query->fetch();

because just public can shown to page.

thanks

Answer (score -2):

define your object like

```
$query = new query($mysqli);
```